# Should I avoid multipart/form requests?

Tags: java, javascript, http, rest

I am creating a RESTful web service and I have created a controller that accepts multipart/form requests.

So I have a POST path like `/cars` which allows upload of a car resource with an image. Would it be better to separate these two into POST `/cars` with only the data and then another one like `/cars/1/images`? Then I want have a multipart/request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One multipart post will work and is the easiest. Otherwise you are basically immatating multipart with a custom POST and request body of which most use base64 to encode the binary of which is not really possible with client JavaScript.